# Is there a way to achieve multiple data binding for a single element in KnockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js

I am a pretty new to the wonderful MVC framework [KnockoutJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KnockoutJS). Is it possible to data bind multiple attributes together?

I want to data-bind [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and style together for a particular element. For example,

I want to data-bind style and CSS together for an element, say `h2` based on some conditions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can data bind multiple attributes. You need to separate each attribute with a comma.

For styling, it sort of depends on what you really want to do.  As a start, check the knockout documentation -

- [CSS Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)
- [Style Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html)
- For really customizable style, take a look at Ryan Niemeyer's fiddle at [Dynamic Styling](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/9Uazw/),

  ```
      var viewModel = {
          size: ko.observable(2)
      };

      viewModel.style = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
          return "h2 { font-size: " + this.size() + "em }";
      }, viewModel);

      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  ```

Comment: That Dynamic Styling fiddle is pretty clever, will have to file that for later.

Comment: @PaulT. - Thats what I thought when I first saw it.